# Animation internally tangent circles, ellipse

Tags: ellipse, circles

I am trying to generate an animation like the gif posted.

[image]

[image]

This is what I have gotten so far. I hope someone can help me finish it.

```
a = 10;
b = 9 Sin[\[Pi]/14];
e = Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]/a;
\[CurlyPhi] = ArcCos[e];

w = Table[-1.2 + 2 j \[CurlyPhi], {j, 0, 6}];
u = Table[a e Sin[-1.2 + 2 j \[CurlyPhi]], {j, 0, 6}];
r = Table[b Cos[-1.2 + 2 j \[CurlyPhi]], {j, 0, 6}];
ParametricPlot[{{a Cos[t], b Sin[t]}, 
  Table[{r[[j]] Cos[t] - u[[j]], r[[j]] Sin[t]}, {j, 1, 7}]}, {t, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

Comment: My code is right. If you want the effect of the original gif,it only need minor modify. But you  downvote my answer without any discussion. I will delete my answer and (-1)

Comment: Your code is not correct for the given problem as stated

Answer (score 8):

**Updated**

```
Clear["`*"];
n=7;
a=10;
b=9 Sin[π/(2n)];
e=Sqrt[a^2-b^2]/a;
φ=ArcCos[e];
Manipulate[Graphics[{
Circle[{0,0},{a,b}],
(*Table[Circle[{a e Sin[#],0},b Cos[#]]&[φ (2 i-n-1)],{i,n}],*)
Table[{If[Cos@#>Sin[φ],{Hue[(i-1)/n],Circle[{a e Sin[#],0},b Cos[#]]}]&/@
{φ (2i+n(2t-1)-1), φ (2i+n(2t-3)-1)}},{i,n}]
}],{t,0,1}]
```

[image]
**Previous answer**

```
Manipulate[Block[{a=1,θ=Pi/(2 n),b:=a Sin[θ]},
Graphics[{
Circle[{0,0},{a,b}],
Table[{If[Sin@#>Sin[θ],{Hue[(i-1)/(n-1)],Disk[{-a Cos[θ] Cos[#],0},a Sin[θ] Sin[#]]}]&/@
{2θ(i+(n-1) t),2θ(i+n+1+(n-1) t)}},{i,n-1}]
},PlotRange->1.1a
]
],{{n,8},2,10},{t,0.,1}]
```

[image]

Comment: As written from the very beginning. I need n=7 and b < a*sin theta